# custom systemd service can't start on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: systemd, bitcoind

and thanks in advance for any assistance

I run original QT wallets (command-line based) for various cryptocurrencies. Earlier this year, I set them up as a custom systemd service, and that has been invaluable. It starts them up and shuts them down with the system just like all the normal services. I recently discovered an issue with one in particular, blackcoin.

This service worked fine in the past (I don't know how long it was down for before I found it)

If I run the command after execstart= command manually, everything works just fine. If I try to start the service (via systemctl start blackcoin), it fails with the following service status:

```
blackcoin.service - blackcoin wallet daemon
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/blackcoin.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Tue 2018-11-20 10:44:01 MST; 2h 51min ago
Process: 12272 ExecStart=/usr/bin/blackcoind -datadir=/coindaemon-rundirectory/blackcoin/ -conf=/coindaemon-rundirectory/blackcoin/blackcoin.conf -daemon (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 12283 (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)

Nov 20 10:44:01 knox systemd[1]: blackcoin.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 20 10:44:01 knox systemd[1]: blackcoin.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Nov 20 10:44:01 knox systemd[1]: Stopped blackcoin wallet daemon.
Nov 20 10:44:01 knox systemd[1]: blackcoin.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 20 10:44:01 knox systemd[1]: blackcoin.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Nov 20 10:44:01 knox systemd[1]: Failed to start blackcoin wallet daemon.
```

Here is the body of the systemd service:

```
##################################################################
##                 Blackcoin Systemd service                    ##
##################################################################
[Unit]
Description=blackcoin wallet daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=somedude
RuntimeDirectory=blackcoind
PIDFile=/run/blackcoind/blackcoind.pid
Restart=on-failure
ExecStart=/usr/bin/blackcoind \
   -datadir=/home/somedude/blackcoin/ \
   -conf=/home/somedude/blackcoin/blackcoin.conf \
   -daemon
ExecStop=/usr/bin/blackcoind \
   -datadir=/home/somedude/blackcoin/ \
   -conf=/home/somedude/blackcoin/blackcoin.conf \
    stop

# Recommended hardening

# Provide a private /tmp and /var/tmp.
PrivateTmp=true

# Mount /usr, /boot/ and /etc read-only for the process.
ProtectSystem=full

# Disallow the process and all of its children to gain
# new privileges through execve().
NoNewPrivileges=true

# Use a new /dev namespace only populated with API pseudo devices
# such as /dev/null, /dev/zero and /dev/random.
PrivateDevices=true

# Deny the creation of writable and executable memory mappings.
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And this is what blackcoin.conf contains:

```
rpcuser=somedude
rpcpassword=12345 (please don't rob my coins!)

# Wallets
wallet=wallet-blackcoin.dat


pid=/run/blackcoind/blackcoind.pid

rpcport=56111
port=56112
```

I'm going to keep testing and will post anything new that I find. Thanks for looking!

Comment: Why run it in forking mode with the -daemon flag? systemd is much happier to run daemons in simple mode, without forking.

Comment: Also, you're getting a core dump. That's a serious code failure. Maybe it is loading the wrong libraries. Does your user account have any special environment variables set?

Comment: As for the forking mode, that's just because I'm new to custom systemd services. I tested one of my other coindaemon services without it, and it works great, so I'll do that from now on. Thank you :)

Comment: I did add some custom environment variables to /etc/environment, but nothing that I think should be a conflict. I just put some in there for thinks like "EXTDOM", which contains my external FQDN. This is just for administration purposes, like cloning golden images of virtual machines. The other six cryptocurrency daemons don't have a problem with the custom environment variables. That's puzzling to me, since the process runs fine outside of systemd with the exact same command as the ExecStart=.   For testing, I'll try making a different user with no environment variables.

Comment: That wasn't well thought out on my part... Environment variables aren't user specific. I'll figure out the easiest way to test that - Maybe I'll just spin up a fresh VM, and see if I can recreate the issue there.

Comment: Doesn't actually seem that the bitcoin daemon worked when I had simple mode on (failed with exit code 28). Switched back to forking and it seems to work again... Is there something else I'm missing in order to get simple mode to work?